# How to show records were 3 fields match

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to write a query that will list the columns in a table when 3 specific fields are the same, but unknown:

**TABLE:**

```
FIELD 1  |   FIELD 2    |  FIELD 3   |   FIELD 4
---------|--------------|------------|---------------
  1      |   01-01-15   |    21      |     150
  1      |   01-01-15   |    24      |      12
  1      |   02-01-15   |    21      |     681
  1      |   01-01-15   |    21      |     299
```

**DESIRED RESULTS:**

```
    FIELD 1  |   FIELD 2    |  FIELD 3    |   FIELD 4
-------------|--------------|-------------|------------
      1      |   01-01-15   |    21       |     150
      1      |   01-01-15   |    21       |     299
```

Sorry - still a newb here!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why return 2 records and not 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the number of rows with the same combination and filter for a count > 1:

```
select *
from tab
qualify 
   count(*) 
   over (partition by field1, field2, field3) > 1
```

Comment: Perfect dnoeth!  I haven't used the qualify statement yet.  Thank You!